# How to add listener to JMX to update?

Tags: java, arraylist, listener, jmx, spring-jmx

Consider the following JMX code:

```
public class UserJMXBeanExpose {
private UserJMXBeanImpl userJMXBean;

@Required
public void setUserJMXBean(UserJMXBeanImpl userJMXBean) {
    this.userJMXBean = userJMXBean;
}



public void init() throws MBeanRegistrationException, InstanceAlreadyExistsException, NotCompliantMBeanException, MalformedObjectNameException {

    MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("MineStar:type=UserJMXBeanExpose,name=Statistics");
    MineStarMBean impl = new MineStarMBean();

    impl.addProperty(new PropertyAdapter("User", "User List", "java.lang.String") {
        public Object getValue() {
            if (userJMXBean == null) return 0;
            return userJMXBean.getUserAttributes();
        }
    });

    server.registerMBean(impl, objectName);
}
}
```

And this code:

```
public class UserJMXBeanImpl implements UserJMXBean {

private  List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

public void addUser(User user){
    userList.add(user);

}

public List<User> getUserList() {
      return userList;
}

public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
    this.userList = userList;
}

public String[] getUserAttributes(){
    for(User user : this.getUserList()){
            return new String[]{user.getUserId(),user.getRoles()};
}
    return null;
}
```

}

How can I add a listener to JMX so that it updates the values of `getUserAttributes()` with the newly added user by `UserJMXBeanImpl` class?

I need to update my jmx information when each new user is added to the impl class. Or how can we add listener so that it can notify the UserJMXBeanExpose to expose its data whenever a new user is added to impl class?

Comment: @Aaron Digulla Need your help here sir. Please have a look.

Comment: @Gray Can I get some help here sir?